# generating adjacency table with R

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix, gephi

I generated an adjacency table `mytable`  with cosine similarity, `m1` is a DTM

```
cosineSim <- function(x){
        as.dist(x%*%t(x)/(sqrt(rowSums(x^2) %*% t(rowSums(x^2)))))
}

cs <- cosineSim(m1)
```

`mytable`

```
"";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8"
"1";0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
"2";0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
"3";0;0;0;0.259;0;0;0;0
"4";0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0.324
"5";0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
"6";0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
"7";0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
"8";0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
```

When I open it with Gephi, I find that the nodes include all the numbers in the table

```
Id  label
"   "   
1"  1"  
2"  2"  
3"  3"  
4"  4"  
5"  5"  
6"  6"  
7"  7"  
8   8   
0   0   
0.259   0.259   
0.324   0.324   
8"  8"
```

I expected the nodes only include 1-8 as ids, not "", "0 and other numbers. Is there something wrong with my adjacency table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double quotes and try to reimport. Since you are using R I would propose to automate your pipeline by using `igraph` and in your case `graph_from_adjacency_matrix`, cf [here](http://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_adjacency_matrix.html). Then you will need to [export](http://igraph.org/r/doc/write_graph.html) the graph in GraphML which Gephi can easily read

Here is some example code for the sake of completeness:

```
library(igraph)
t <- ';1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
3;0;0;0;0.259;0;0;0;0
4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0.324
5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
6;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
7;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
8;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0'

f <- read.csv(textConnection(t), sep = ";", header = T, row.names = 1)
m <- as.matrix(f, rownames.force = T)
colnames(m) <- seq(1:dim(f)[1])
rownames(m) <- seq(1:dim(f)[1])
graph <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, mode=c("directed"), weighted = T)
write.graph(graph, "mygraph.graphml", format=c("graphml") )
```